# NancyFx not reaching module using Owin Hosting

Tags: nancy, owin

I am trying to create a really simple NancyFx project using OWIN hosting.

Nancy appears to be running because I get the 404 that comes with Nancy by default, but none of my modules are ever reached.

Here is what I have so far.
It is probably something really obvious.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebApplication.Start<Startup>("http://+:8080"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.cs

```
class HelloWorld : Nancy.NancyModule
{
    public HelloWorld()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters =>
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to make your module public, right now it's private

Comment: You sir, are the smartest man alive.  I feel dumb, but thanks :)

Comment: @Alex You are not alone in your dumbitude. This solved the same issue for me :-)